# Python3 - How can I access method parameter from a differernt module

Tags: function, parameters

FILE0.py

```
import file1
import file2
"""
main file
somewhere down in the code
"""
file1.makeMove_Maybe1(piece,destination,figureitout)
```

FILE1.py

```
import file2
class chess-move:
    __init__():
        maybe1 = None
        maybe2 = None

    def MakeMove_maybe1(piece,destination,decision):
        file2.executeMove(piece,destination,holdfingeronit)

    def analyzeOppMove(piece,oldloc,newloc,didIloseapiece):
        code = irrelevant
        """
        code irrelevant it is example anyway
        or just say logic is elsewhere and this was call
        from file0
        """

def makeMove_Maybe1(piece,destination,decision):
```

> """
>          Long doc string.  Boss likes accessors methods
>          instead of calling class methods directly from other
>          code. And I have no authority to access file0(the driver)
>          I do have authority over all other files.
>   """

```
   myMove.MakeMove_maybe1(piece,destination,decision)
```

FILE2.py

```
import flle1
class testmove:
    __init__():
        objvar1 = None
```

> """
>              I want a variable HERE 
>              to be initialized ,and set to for each iteration, to the
>              the destination variable from file1, whether from
>              in the class or outside the class.
>              PLEASE help, I cannot figure this out. OO is new
>              to me.  I am also hoping the code is correct.
>              I can also strip down the real code for follow if
>              required.
>   """

Answer (score 0):

### Real Problem

*Piece* in the example above was in my code as **myAgent.siprtp.namedata**, and I needed to get a path variable (*destination* parameter in the example) into File2's class method.  But that path was added into the **myAgent** object and there was no inheritance from its class.

### My Solution

So File2's class method (**Get_File_From_Path**) could not access the path I needed.  Therefore, I called the method in File1 (which was **GetFileFromPath**) with **myAgent** acting as self, which mentioned above should have been **myAgent.siprtp.namedata**.  When the 'fake' self made it to File2 I used it to extract my required path, and then built back up the 'correct' self so File2's methods could use the proper self.

Hope that made sense, and hope this might be able to assist someone.